# How to join 'generic data model' using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have an existing DB schema that cannot be changed easily. Some of the tables are properly set up, i.e. fields are mapped to columns, but others store key-value pairs together with a foreign key, such as

```
FK | Key | Value
1  | foo | 10
1  | bar | 11
2  | bar | 99
3  | foo | 333
3  | bar | 334
3  | baz | 335
```

FK is the foreign key identifying entities in my other (properly set up) table.

How can I make a fixed subset of `Key`s (e.g. `foo` and `bar` only) appear as attributes on my entities in the properly set up table using Hibernate?

Comment: you want to filter based on Key column?

Comment: No, I want to use Hibernate Search, once it is available as attribute, by applying an `@Field` annotation.